# Flutter build apk release crashing when opening the app only in first time

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Apparently the error is actually in the main.dart -- crashing when opening the app only in first time

I am developing a flutter application with a welcome screen that appears only the first time the app is opened, after that the main screen is a webview

This is my main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.amber,
      home: new Splash(),
    );
  }
}

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SplashState createState() => new SplashState();
}

class SplashState extends State<Splash> with AfterLayoutMixin<Splash> {
  Future checkFirstSeen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);

    if (_seen) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Home()));
    } else {
      await prefs.setBool('seen', true);
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new IntroScreen()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) => checkFirstSeen();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('Carregando...'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Entrega na Obra',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class IntroScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Entrega na Obra',
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the details of the actual error you're getting.

Comment: Also, what is `WelcomeScreen()` in your code?